# TSQL - how to tell if SQL is clustered?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cluster-computing

Is there a way using TSQL, CMD Script or VB Script to tell:

1) if SQL Server is clustered on the server, and

2) if it is the active node or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Both of these can be found using

```
 SELECT * FROM fn_virtualservernodes()
```

If there are no results, it's not clustered.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and it also provides information about the cluster status. (UP or DOWN for each cluster node.)

Answer (score 9):

For active node you may try this to check the name of the node on which the clustered SQL Server instance is running on:

```
Select ServerProperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')
```

and for checking if its clustered:

```
SELECT 'IsClustered', SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')
```

Also check this **[article](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Determining%20which%20node%20a%20clustered%20SQL%20Server%20is%20running%20on.aspx)** and [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx).

Comment: Sorry to be slow, but how does this tell me whether it is the active node or not?

Comment: @Neilw:- Check this:- http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Determining%20which%20node%20a%20clustered%20SQL%20Server%20is%20running%20on.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, is there a way of determining if it is clustered even without starting SQL Server? E.g., from a CMD or VBS script? Is there a Service Name I can look for?