# Query to get servername, instancename, machine_name, database_name, recovery model, isclustered in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need query to get server_name, instance_name, machine_name, database_name, recovery_model, isclustered in SQL Server 2012 and above.

Thanks

Comment: Without any further information, good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql) view and add few [`SERVERPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql) metadata informations.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS MachineName,
        SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS ServerName,
        name AS DatabaseName,
        recovery_model_desc AS RecoveryModel
FROM sys.databases
```

Getting information about Cluster is described here:

[TSQL - how to tell if SQL is clustered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347370/tsql-how-to-tell-if-sql-is-clustered)

[How to find SQLServer Virtual Cluster name](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/19b1fed3-0239-4855-8a4e-067dc31c1325/how-to-find-sqlserver-virtual-cluster-name?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

Comment: In above query machinename is giving a cluster name, I need to get node name instead of clustername, and also is there a way to add isclustered ti above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
SELECT  
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS ComputerName,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS InstanceName,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
  SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS IsClustered,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel;  
GO
```

More details on properties : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql

> THIS TOPIC APPLIES TO:
>
> - SQL Server (starting with 2008)
> - Azure SQL Database
> - Azure SQL Data
> - Warehouse  Parallel Data Warehouse
>
> Returns property information about the server instance.

Comment: Hi, I am looking query with all database names in that instance with recovery model and with instance name, machine_name, servername details...I need to make a inventory.